# How to optimize rendering in Angular?

Tags: angular

I render array of object in template using **ngFor**:

```
<tr *ngFor="let p of rows; let i = index">
        <td class="tableDefault__td tableDefault__center td__number">
          {{ i + 1 }}
        </td>
        <td class="tableDefault__td tableDefault__center td__date">
          <div class="history_item" *ngFor="let h of p.history">
            <span class="span_link" (click)="goto(h)"
              >{{ h.classNumber }}{{ h.classSuffix }},
              {{ formatDate(h.whenDate) }}</span
            >
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="tableDefault__td tableDefault__center td__theme">
          <input
            [disabled]="!isOwner(teacherId)"
            type="text"
            name="subject"
            placeholder="{{ 'create_plan_e_name' | translate }}"
            [(ngModel)]="p.topic"
            autofocus
          />
        </td>
</tr>
```

Rendering works so slowly when array `rows` container more then 400 objects. How to optimize rendering or cache it? Perhaps problem is in nested loop `*ngFor="let h of p.history"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `trackBy` function in you `ngFor` directive to improve performance by providing an unique id. It allows Angular to better handle the change detection concerning the array you bound.

Something like:

**HTML**

```html
<tr *ngFor="let p of rows; trackBy: trackByFunction; let i = index">
    ....
</tr>
```

**TS**

```js
public trackByFunction(index, item) {
    if (item) {
        return item.id;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here is a good [example](https://medium.com/@ramy_ali/improving-angular-ngfor-performance-through-trackby-ae4cf943b878).

And the official [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf).

Comment: Track by accepts custom function, what function should return? Why do you return item.id instead item?

Comment: It must return an unique identifier so that Angular can only reload specific elements in you array and not the whole array when a change is detected.